# How to include related models Django

Tags: django, django-models

I have 3 models:

```
class ImageAlbum(models.Model):
def default(self):
    return self.images.filter(default=True).first()
def thumbnails(self):
    return self.images.filter(width__lt=100, length_lt=100)

class Image(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')
    default = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    width = models.FloatField(default=100)
    length = models.FloatField(default=100)
    album = models.ForeignKey(ImageAlbum, related_name='images', on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    price = models.IntegerField()
    description = models.TextField(max_length=2000, help_text="This is the description of the product")
    images = models.OneToOneField(ImageAlbum, related_name='model', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

When I'm selecting product models

```
Product.objects
```

In the `Product` field `images` I'm having only the primary key of album.
I want to get related `ImageAlbum` and all related `Image` for each `ImageAlbum` when I'm selecting `Product` model.
Appreciate any help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but i think that this is how you would do it:

```
product = Product.objects.get(pk=pk) # query the product
images = product.images.default()
thumbnails = product.images.thumbnails()
```

So in order to do this with many products you should really get rid of the `ImageAlbum` model because it's really unnecessary, you can just tie the **image** the the **product** and that set of images will be the image album (sort of) (if you want to store thumbnails you can manually do that for your image model (just have 2 images in 1 object))

After that migration use **Prefetch** to get the children:

```
from django.db.models import Prefetch


products = Product.objects.all()
images = Image.objects.prefetch_related(
    Prefetch(
        'images', # the related name
        Product.objects.all(), # queryset
        to_attr='product_images' # attribute for usage in the template
    )
)
```

**your_template.html**

```
{% for product im products %}
    {% for image in product.product_images %}
        ...
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Can I do it on one query? Or should I go through every product and then through every album to get images for product?